# How can I find if a column is auto_increment in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to inspect my mysql database information_schema to find out the attributes of the columns.  I can't find where the details as to which columns are auto_increment.  Does anyone know where I can find this info in the information_schema DB?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

see the EXTRA column in the COLUMNS table:

```
select * from COLUMNS where  TABLE_SCHEMA='yourschema' and TABLE_NAME='yourtable' and EXTRA like '%auto_increment%'
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use

```
mysql> DESCRIBE yourtable;
```

Example:

```
mysql> use my_database;
mysql> describe users;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| password | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email    | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```