# Select the column name of a table which is auto increment

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i get the column name of a table which is auto increment?

i have a code to get all my table

and i want to select each of their auto increment column.

```
   $tables = $this->sql("SHOW TABLES");

   foreach($tables as $tb)
   {

       //here i waant to select the  auto increment of the table
   }
```

how can i do that?

Comment: So what's in `$tb`? What would your next step be?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468664/how-can-i-find-if-a-column-is-auto-increment-in-mysql?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468664/how-can-i-find-if-a-column-is-auto-increment-in-mysql?rq=1   this post helps ;) thanks

Comment: A quick search of the archives probably would have answered the question in less time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   COLUMNS 
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourschema'  AND 
       EXTRA = 'auto_increment'
```

Answer (score 1):

use `mysqli_fetch_fields()` which gives an array of attributes about the table fields. One field in this array is called `FLAGS` which represents the various flags that has been set for the field such as PRIMARY_KEY, UNIQUE_KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG etc..

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
$tables = $this->sql("SHOW TABLES");

foreach($tables as $tb)
{

  $result = mysqli_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$tb);
  if (!$result) {
     echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
     exit;
   }
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     $autoincrement_field = array();
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     if($row['Extra'] === "auto_increment"){
        $autoincrement_field[] = aray($tb => $row['field']);
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Which give output of what you want..

For more information have a look at the [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php)

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of column names in a table, run this Mysql query: `SHOW COLUMNS $tablename`.  Do try this harmless and informative statement on your own just to see what it returns.  For more info on what this query actually does, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.htm

The "Key" column in the returned query results will contain a value of "PRI" *if* it's a primary key.

Make sure `$tablename` is a real table - *absolutely do not accept user input* for this value as it would be a *severe* security risk.